# Angular repeat is not updating style

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with my angular repeater. This is the first time that I've really tried angular and I am trying to build a repeater for employees that a manager has.  The repeater works as intended when I change how many employees per row to show it filters the list and displays the right number of employees on each row.  However there is a  that acts as a horizontal connector for all employees that's width does not change.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="n in chart.renderRange(chart.data.employees.length,chart.employeeRenderBoxes)"
     class="horizontalConnector"
     ng-style="{'width': {{ chart.calcEmployeesHorizontalRowWidth((chart.data.employees| paging:n-1:chart.employeeRenderBoxes).length) }} + 'px' }"></div>
<table ng-repeat-end class="employeeNav" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('chartController', chartController);

chartController.$inject = ['$log', 'bootstrappedData'];

function chartController($log, bootstrappedData) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.employeeRenderBoxes = 4;
    vm.employeeRenderRange = 0;
    vm.data = bootstrappedData.chartData;

    vm.renderRange = renderRange;
    vm.calcEmployeesHorizontalRowWidth = calcEmployeesHorizontalRowWidth;

    function renderRange(employeeCount, employeeRenderBoxes) {
        var _range = [];
        var numberOfSplits = Math.ceil(employeeCount / ((!!employeeRenderBoxes) ? employeeRenderBoxes : 1));
        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSplits; i += 1) {
            _range.push(i);
        }
        vm.employeeRenderRange = _range.length;
        return _range;
    }

    function calcEmployeesHorizontalRowWidth(rangeCounter) {
        return (rangeCounter - 1) * 130;
    }
}
})();
```

What I find odd is that the rendered HTML shows that the width changes but the style remains unchanged.

```
<div ng-repeat-start="n in chart.renderRange(chart.data.employees.length,chart.employeeRenderBoxes)" class="horizontalConnector ng-scope" ng-style="{'width': 390 + 'px' }" style="width: 650px;"></div>
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on with my angular code?

Comment: At least remove the curly braces from the ng-style, `ng-style="{ 'width': myExpression }"` - check this simple plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Ka8iooNkYH84YmkGoONm?p=preview

Comment: thanks @Fissio  that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the {{}} from my ngstyle

```
<div ng-repeat-start="n in chart.renderRange(chart.data.employees.length,chart.employeeRenderBoxes)"
 class="horizontalConnector"
 ng-style="{'width': chart.calcEmployeesHorizontalRowWidth((chart.data.employees| paging:n-1:chart.employeeRenderBoxes).length) + 'px' }"></div>
```